# Mysql where and multiple like not working

Tags: mysql, sql-like

```
SELECT * FROM (`users`) 
JOIN `groups` ON `users`.`groupid` = `groups`.`group_id` 
WHERE `groupid` = `1`
AND `first_name` LIKE '%john%' 
OR `last_name` LIKE '%john%' 
OR `username` LIKE '%john%'
OR `email` LIKE '%john%' 
LIMIT 25
```

This query for searching users on user fields with LIKE and in specific user group with WHERE sql command.

But LIKE command overriding to WHERE. Result is;

```
id        groupid        firstname
===================================
2         3              john doe
5         2              johny dash
```

In results groupid is 3 but have to be 1

I dont want to use LIKE command on equaling.

```
WHERE `groupid` LIKE `1`
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (`users`) 
JOIN `groups` ON `users`.`groupid` = `groups`.`group_id` 
WHERE `groupid` = `1`
AND (
      `first_name` LIKE '%john%' 
       OR `last_name` LIKE '%john%' 
       OR `username` LIKE '%john%'
       OR `email` LIKE '%john%' 
)
LIMIT 25
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (`users`) 
JOIN `groups` ON `users`.`groupid` = `groups`.`group_id` 
WHERE `groupid` = `1`
AND `first_name` LIKE '%john%' 
OR `last_name` LIKE '%john%' 
OR `username` LIKE '%john%'
OR `email` LIKE '%john%' 
LIMIT 25
```

should be

```
SELECT * FROM (`users`) 
JOIN `groups` ON `users`.`groupid` = `groups`.`group_id` 
WHERE `groupid` = `1`
AND 
(
    `first_name` LIKE '%john%' 
    OR `last_name` LIKE '%john%' 
    OR `username` LIKE '%john%'
    OR `email` LIKE '%john%' 
)
LIMIT 25
```